# Copying packed record to TByteDynArray in delphi (10 Seattle)

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to copy a `packed record` to `TByteDynArray` in Delphi.

```
PMyRec = ^TMyRec;
TMyRec = packed record
  Header: THeaderRec;
  Timestamp: TTimeStamp;   // time of event
  PLoc: TLocationRec;
  A: word;
end;
```

Below is the code snippet that I have for doing that.

```
  xxx: TByteDynArray;
  m_arr : TMyRec;

  SetLength(xxx,sizeof(TMyRec));

  offset := offset + sizeof(THeaderRec);
  System.Move(xxx[offset], m_arr.Timestamp ,sizeof(TTimeStamp));

  offset := offset + sizeof(TTimeStamp);
  System.Move(xxx[offset], m_arr.PLoc,sizeof(TLocationRec));
```

This somehow doesn't seem to do the copying properly. Can someone point out if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you're actually trying to do. What are you trying to accomplish? The simplest way would be to simply move the record directly into the array as a linear block of memory,  but as it's not clear what your intent is it's difficult to see if that solution will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to copy **FROM** the record **TO** the byte array, then your code is doing the opposite.  Pay attention to the parameters of `System.Move()`.  Its first parameter is the *Source*, its second parameter is the *Destination*.  This is different than other APIs, like `memcpy()`, `CopyMemory()`, etc.

Try this:

```
offset := 0;
System.Move(m_arr.Header, xxx[offset], sizeof(THeaderRec));

Inc(offset, sizeof(THeaderRec));
System.Move(m_arr.Timestamp, xxx[offset], sizeof(TTimeStamp));

Inc(offset, sizeof(TTimeStamp));
System.Move(m_arr.PLoc, xxx[offset], sizeof(TLocationRec));

Inc(offset, sizeof(TLocationRec));
System.Move(m_arr.A, xxx[offset], sizeof(Word));
```

Or, you can copy the entire record in one go:

```
System.Move(m_arr, xxx[0], sizeof(TMyRec));
```

With that said, if you need to do per-field copies, I would suggest letting the compiler calculate the field offsets for you, eg:

```
offset := Integer(@PMyRec(nil).Header);
System.Move(m_arr.Header, xxx[offset], sizeof(THeaderRec));

offset := Integer(@PMyRec(nil).Timestamp);
System.Move(m_arr.Timestamp, xxx[offset], sizeof(TTimeStamp));

offset := Integer(@PMyRec(nil).PLoc);
System.Move(m_arr.PLoc, xxx[offset], sizeof(TLocationRec));

offset := Integer(@PMyRec(nil).A);
System.Move(m_arr.A, xxx[offset], sizeof(Word));
```

Or better, simply do not use `Move()` at all.  You can instead type-cast the allocated byte array and use standard field assignments, eg:

```
PMyRec(xxx)^.Header := m_arr.Header;
PMyRec(xxx)^.Timestamp := m_arr.Timestamp;
PMyRec(xxx)^.PLoc := m_arr.PLoc;
PMyRec(xxx)^.A := m_arr.A;
```

Or, to copy the entire record:

```
PMyRec(xxx)^ := m_arr;
```